Uber Direct API - Create Delivery API returns "invalid restaurant gateway request"
I've just started to play with this API on the Uber sandbox.
I've successfully created a quote with a POST to delivery_quotes
When I then make a create delivery call to POST deliveries and supplying a quote from above, the API returns:
{ "code": "invalid_params", "message": "The parameters of your request were invalid.", "kind": "error", "metadata": { "param_details": "invalid restaurant gateway request" } }
I'm obviously doing something wrong but not sure what.
My test POST payload is:
{
  "dropoff_address": "1 Lincoln Street, Boston, MA 02111",
  "dropoff_name": "Arthur Daley",
  "dropoff_phone_number": "+0299",
  "manifest_items": [
    {
      "name": "Medications",
      "quantity": 3,
      "size": "small"}
  ],
  "pickup_address": "4 LIBERTY SQ,BOSTON, MA 02109-4811, USA",
  "pickup_name": "Dr Susan Smith",
  "pickup_phone_number": "+72704",
  "pickup_business_name": "CVS Drug Store",
  "pickup_notes": "Keep refrigerated",
  "pickup_verification": {
    "signature": true,
    "signature_requirement": {
      "enabled": true,
      "collect_signer_name": true,
      "collect_signer_relationship": false
    },
    "barcodes": [
      {
        "value": "<string>",
        "type": "CODE128"
      }
    ],
    "identification": {
      "min_age": 18
    },
    "picture": false
  },
  "deliverable_action": "deliverable_action_meet_at_door",
  "manifest_reference": "<string>",
  "manifest_total_value": 200,
  "quote_id": "dqt_UXFtqGTlQ9Oai1dbMkWd-w",
  "undeliverable_action": "return",
  "pickup_ready_dt": "2024-04-04T14:00:00.000Z",
  "requires_dropoff_signature": true,
  "requires_id": false,
  "tip": 0,
  "idempotency_key": "<string>",
  "test_specifications": {
        "robo_courier_specification": {
            "mode": "auto"
        }
    }
}

See above. Expecting a success result

I had this same error for Uber Direct at my company and the fix is simple for us. In our case, it's the phone number that is invalid from our side, either  the country code which is at the start of the number is incorrect/missing or there is a space at the end of the phone number.
Even though it has been 4 months for this post, I hope this answer helps anyone in future.
